# Dart Mockito - How to mock while keep the original implementation?

Tags: flutter, dart, mocking, mockito, flutter-test

I would like to write some integration tests on my flutter app. To do so I am using the package [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito).

---

**I would like to mock a class but also keep its original implementation.**

Let's say I have a model `MyModel` (which can be complex) and a widget using it.

```dart
class MyModel {
    void complexCallback() {}
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyWidget(this.model);
    
    final MyModel model;
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
}
```

I would like to be able in a test to mock `MyModel` to verify the callback function is called (for example after a tap on a button), but I would also want `MyModel` to behave as it should to verify the repercussions on the screen (rebuild of the widget with different values for example).

```dart
testWidget('Test MyModel and MyWidget', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final model = MyModel(); // <- Cannot verify here because it is not mocked, if I replace by MockMyModel or FakeMyModel, the button doesn't do anything anymore
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyWidget(model));

    await tester.tap(find.byType(IconButton));  // <- Tap on a button for example

    expect(find.text('Button tapped'), findsOneWidget); // <- Test change on the screen - works with MyModel but not with MockMyModel and FakeMyModel
    expect(verify(model.complexCallback(captureAny)).captured, ['buttonID']); // <- Test callback function - works with MockMyModel or FakeMyModel but not with MyModel
});
```

---

The issue I have is that if I run the test as it is, `MyModel` is not mocked, so `verify` won't work.

If I mock it using `Mock` or `Fake` from [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito):

```dart
class MockMyModel extends Mock implements MyModel {}
```

or

```dart
class FakeMyModel extends Fake implements MyModel {}
```

I will lose the implementation of `MyModel` and then, the screen won't change after a tap. And I don't really want to override all the methods of `MyModel` which can be pretty big and complex. Also if I rewrite it, I will then test my overridden implementation and not the original one which is not really the point.

---

Any idea how I could achieve it?

Comment: Don't mock your model but the API or DAO.

Comment: Hello @Isaudon, I am not sure I am getting what you mean here could you elaborate?

Comment: Your `complexCallback` method uses external API REST or Database.
You need to mock this one.

Comment: Oh ok, but unfortunately, it is not using any external API REST or Database.